# How to achieve Polars' previous `pivot()` functionality pre 0.20.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

Previous to Polars version `0.20.7`, the `pivot()` method, if given multiple values for the `columns` argument, would apply the aggregation logic against each column in `columns` **individually** based on the `index` column, rather than against a collective set of columns.

Before:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": ["one", "one", "two", "two", "one", "two"],
        "bar": ["y", "y", "y", "x", "x", "x"],
        "biz": ['m', 'f', 'm', 'f', 'm', 'f'],
        "baz": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    }
)

df.pivot(index='foo', values='baz', columns=('bar', 'biz'), aggregate_function='sum')
```

returns:

```
shape: (2, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ y   ┆ x   ┆ m   ┆ f   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ one ┆ 3   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 2   │
│ two ┆ 3   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

After (in [`0.20.7`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/14048)):

```
shape: (2, 5)
┌─────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ foo ┆ {"y","m"} ┆ {"y","f"} ┆ {"x","f"} ┆ {"x","m"} │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ i64       ┆ i64       ┆ i64       ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ one ┆ 1         ┆ 2         ┆ null      ┆ 5         │
│ two ┆ 3         ┆ null      ┆ 10        ┆ null      │
└─────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

I like the previous functionality much better; it's very awkward to deal with the new pivoted table, especially given its column names. Polars devs put this change under "Bug fixes" but it actually broke my code.

Comment: Do a `group_by("foo","bar").agg(pl.col("baz").sum())` before you pivot.

Comment: Incidentally, you're the first person I've seen defend the old behavior between GitHub issues and discord.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor thanks for the comment! But what about column `biz`? Interesting, I find the previous implementation to be very direct and intuitive tbh; also, accessing the pivoted columns is really awkward.

Comment: I think main issue with the previous behaviour was that it allowed duplicate column names to be created in some cases: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/14048

Comment: `.melt(["foo", "baz"]).pivot()` may be the simplest thing to do in this case

Comment: I'd say new functionality is cleaner in a way that total sum of `baz` stays the same. If you want to replicate old functionality you can always do `df.melt(["foo", "baz"]).drop('variable').pivot(index='foo', values='baz', columns='value', aggregate_function='sum')`

Comment: Sorry for my wrong advice on the group_by, I was on mobile so didn't check it. Sorry that you "won" the [workflow lottery](https://xkcd.com/1172/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a couple of ways you could do it:

First, you can use [`melt()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html) for your DataFrame first and then pivot:

```py
df.melt(["foo", "baz"])

─────┬─────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ foo ┆ baz ┆ variable ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ str      ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ one ┆ 1   ┆ bar      ┆ y     │
│ one ┆ 2   ┆ bar      ┆ y     │
│ two ┆ 3   ┆ bar      ┆ y     │
│ two ┆ 4   ┆ bar      ┆ x     │
│ one ┆ 5   ┆ bar      ┆ x     │
│ …   ┆ …   ┆ …        ┆ …     │
│ one ┆ 2   ┆ biz      ┆ f     │
│ two ┆ 3   ┆ biz      ┆ m     │
│ two ┆ 4   ┆ biz      ┆ f     │
│ one ┆ 5   ┆ biz      ┆ m     │
│ two ┆ 6   ┆ biz      ┆ f     │
└─────┴─────┴──────────┴───────┘
```

and then pivot the same way:

```py
(
   df
   .melt(["foo", "baz"])
   .pivot(index='foo', values='baz', columns='value', aggregate_function='sum')
)

┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ y   ┆ x   ┆ m   ┆ f   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ one ┆ 3   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 2   │
│ two ┆ 3   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Alternatively, if lists of possible values are not intersecting between columns you need to aggregate, you could use [`concat()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html) with `how` = `align`:

```py
pl.concat(
    [df.pivot(index='foo', values='baz', columns=col, aggregate_function="sum") for col in ['bar','biz']],
    how='align'
)

┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ y   ┆ x   ┆ m   ┆ f   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ one ┆ 3   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 2   │
│ two ┆ 3   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Nice solution! I think explicitly dropping the *variable* column in the `melt()` solution is not needed though, no?

Comment: @Hericks indeed you're right, it's just a remaining piece of code I had during cleaning up the melted part. I'll update the answer

Comment: @RomanPekar Thanks; love the `melt()` solution as it avoids the need to loop. I didn't quite understand the need for the alternative solution, though. Do you mind elaborating on it please (the `melt()` solution seems to work fine for all cases to me)?

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi in this case i’m not sure which solutuon would perform better, you can test it on your data though

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using `group_by`

```
pl.concat([
    df.group_by('foo',pl.col(x).alias('mix'), maintain_order=True)
      .agg(pl.col('baz').sum())
    for x in ['bar','biz']
]).pivot('baz','foo','mix','first')

shape: (2, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ y   ┆ x   ┆ m   ┆ f   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ one ┆ 3   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 2   │
│ two ┆ 3   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

Use concat:

```py
pl.concat(
    [
        df.pivot(index="foo", values="baz", columns="bar", aggregate_function="sum"),
        df.pivot(
            index="foo", values="baz", columns="biz", aggregate_function="sum"
        ).drop("foo"),
    ],
    how="horizontal",
)
```

```
Out[11]:
shape: (2, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ y   ┆ x   ┆ m   ┆ f   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ one ┆ 3   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 2   │
│ two ┆ 3   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```